# A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform cannot be published to SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

Migrating from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2012.

In this solution contains database projects also, In 2012 there is not database project concept so i converted into sql project (Changed the sql Target version 2008 to 2012) after that i can able to compile the project with no error. While building this project,

I'm facing this issue while building vs2012 sql project

> A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform
>   cannot be published to SQL Server 2008
>   [image]

Note : Our previous sql version was sql server 2008

Comment: So your solution isn't compatible with 2008. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @RichBenner , I migrated my solution into vs2012 and sqlserver 2012.But still shows this error.